# French Pronunciation Dictionary

Tags: pronunciation, french, dictionary, resource-request

Is there a French pronunciation dictionary on the web like [CMU](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) English dictionary?
Thanks.

Comment: The CNRTL dictionary has a ["Morphologie"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/) tab that shows the pronunciation of each form of a word, using [SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Assessment_Methods_Phonetic_Alphabet).

Comment: @sumelic SAMPA?? Eew. Why not convert to unicode IPA?

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Page_d%E2%80%99accueil) is for most major languages pretty well equipped in terms of pronounciation.

Comment: It's not always accurate.